# Specifying a relative path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directory, filepath

I have a windows forms project. In the current directory I have a Help folder with *.chm files. What is the easiest way to launch them from the application? How can I specify the relative path to them?

Comment: By 'current' directory do you mean 'working' directory or 'resident' directory?

Comment: I suppose, it is working directory.

Comment: try to write path: "Help/"+filename

Comment: It is the name of the file. How can I launch that file?

Comment: if in std program: Process.Start("Help/123.chm");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Help.ShowHelp to do this

```
var chmFile = "CHM/test.chm";
Help.ShowHelp(ctrl, chmFile);
```

by default ShowHelp will search file in the application path

Answer (score 7):

The [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) property will be set to the location of your .exe file. So if you place your help folder in there, it will be:

```
// The path to the Help folder.
string directory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Help"); 

// The path to the Help file.
string filePath = Path.Combine(directory , "myHelpFile.chm"); 

// Launch the Help file.
Process.Start(filePath);
```

EDIT: I should say, that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` points to the folder where the process started by default in a Windows Forms application, but its value can be changed by some controls (like the `OpenFileDialog` - see [here for a workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c)) during the lifetime of your application. Under a Windows Service, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` maps to the `%SystemDirectory%`.

Comment: `Path.Combine` can take > 2 parameters, so you could just say `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Help", "myHelpFile.chm")`

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory is not a path to the application

Comment: @RichTea - I never realised that. Just been looking at the docs and it seems that a bunch of overloads appeared in C# 4.0. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two options, depending on what you *actually* want. The first is to get the path to the *resident* directory (where the executing files live) and the second concerns the *current* directory (the directory specified for the executable to work from):

*Resident directory*:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

*Current directory*:

```
var path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

There is also another option, which, according to documentation `gets the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name`:

```
var path = Application.StartupPath;
```

As for constructing your path, other answers cover that very well indeed.

Comment: Correct way is: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase

Comment: Thank you. I actually needed a resident directory.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is

```
Process.Start("myHelpFile.chm");
```

This will open the `chm` file in the systems default program associated with that file type.

This will work as long as the chm file is located in the same directory as your exe. If you have a sub folder called help, the path will be `@"Help\myHelpFile.chm"`.