# How to start a program with process.start without that the program can't find it's files

Tags: c#, exe

I'm trying to make a program, which can open other programs, but I need help, because if I run a program,  with

```
Process.Start(ExePath)
```

I get errors like 'cannot find 'File.*' file'.
but normally the program works when I start it manually it just works normally
does someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `ExePath`?

Comment: What's the value of ExePath? And does that precise executable exist in your system?

Comment: You need to set the correct working directory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory .

Comment: For example: 
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\Games\\Game.exe"

Comment: That will make it dependent on where your program is run from, which isn't necessarily the same directory as the assembly. You should use the absolute path of your executing assembly as the root in this instance, if the Game.exe always exists in the Games subfolder of the executing assembly.

Comment: make a breakpoint at `Process.Start(...)` and check the value of `ExePath`). Then open the explorer and check if the exact path exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a full qualified path starting from your current application directory like this:

```
string exepath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Games", "Game.exe");
Process.Start(exepath);
```

<sub>adopted from [Specifying a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077532/205233)</sub>