# Running external executable from C# solution with relative path

Tags: c#, .net

I get a `Win32Exception` `File not found` when trying to run an external executable (with dependencies) from a C# solution with the following code.

```
public static string TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine("dist", @"test.exe");
        p.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        expMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return expMessage;
}
```

Remarks:

- No exception occurs when an absolute path is specified as `FileName`.
- In MS Visual Studio the `dist` subfolder files properties are set to the following and the `dist`directory is indeed copied into the output folder:

  - `Build action: Content`
  - `Always copy in output directory`
- I have tried with a `test.exe.config` file as follows but with no success:

> 

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="dist"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**  The only solution proposed in [Specifying a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5077475/3416205) which actually works in this case is the one eventually provided as a comment by  Viacheslav Smityukh combining `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase` to reconstruct the absolute path. However there seems to be a potential issue at runtime as stated in Pavel Pája Halbich's answer below. From [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837488/3416205) I found out another solution based on Mr.Mindor's comment using the following code:

```
string uriPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
string testpath = Path.Combine(localPath, "dist", @"test.exe");
```

Now I wonder which one is the proper way considering a future deployment of the solution with Window Installer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077475/specifying-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to `dist` in your case is the current working directory, which isn't aligning with your expectations.

Try changing your path to:

`Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "dist", @"test.exe");`

Comment: You have two flaws - first, you are using just string instead of `BaseDirectory` property in a first parameter in `Path.Combine`. Moreover, `BaseDirectory` could be set in runtime, thus it is not a good practice (but it could work)

Comment: @Connor Thanks: it works as expected when combining `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. However as it seems not to be recommended, is it satisfactory? Especially if I want to distribute the solution with Windows Installer later? I am surprised there is no canonical way to perform such a standard task.

Comment: @AntoineGautier It's the way I've always done it. Pavel is right in that it can be set to something different when the AppDomain is created, but unless you're working with AppDomains (creating or destroying), you should be safe to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **full** path to that executable. So you can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` resulting in

```
Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( iSystem.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "dist", @"test.exe");
```

As you can se in this question [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application), using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` could work, but it is not recommened - it could be changed in runtime.

**EDIT** corrected answer for getting directory instead of full location to executable.

Comment: I have already tried combining `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`. In my case it returns `C:\Users\Ang\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\967GPNG9.0M7\DMDMB1C2.7XQ\b710451e\c711a674_7f05d301` and does not solve the issue. Even manually adding `dist` subfolder to this location during runtime does not help.

Comment: I think the challenge with this approach is that it doesn't account for shadow copies, like if you are running the program from a network share for example. The assembly and folder you are technically looking for reside on the server and are not in the local copy that is being executed.